# Xcode 6.0.1 Segmentation Fault 11

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I cannot build my project due to an error(Segmentation Fault 11). With commenting things out, I found that the error is thrown by this line:

```
typealias functionType = ([Expression], [String: NSNumber], inout AnyObject) -> Expression!;
```

If I remove the typealias and use the raw type instead, the error gets still thrown, so the mistake is probably not the typealias, but the closure.

**Edit:**
If I replace the type `Expression` with `AnyObject` the error gets still thrown. But if I just declare the typealias, I can use it for a global variable but not for a member variable.

Comment: This is not crushing on my machine, whether I declare `Expression` to be a protocol, a class, a struct, or enum... There is something about `Expression`, though, that is likely causing this. Can you divulge a little bit more about `Expression`?

Comment: On a side note, you do not need a semicolon at the end, and `functionType` would be better off with a capital `F`, it wouldn't be so lonely, a freak, among other types... Also, out of curiosity, why are you returning an implicitly unwrapped optional (the `Expression!`)?

Comment: @milos Expression is a class that holds some information about the mathematical expression
I'm returning Expression! because the result might be nil, but I don't like to use Swifts '?', so I use the inout parameter usually for a Bool and if the Bool is true I stop the programm

Comment: Right... what I meant about divulging a little more about `Expression` (which one can guess models a mathematical expression) is: (1) does it inherit from another class? (2) does it implement any protocols? and, in particular, (3) does it implement an associated type?

Comment: As for optionals in Swift, used sparsely, they are one of the most powerful features of the language. In a long run, getting used to programming patterns that are meant to be encouraged by it is probably a wise strategy... Really, I am sure `?` will grow on you!

Comment: It inherits from NSObject and implements the NSCopying protocol, but I don't understand what you mean with (3)

Comment: `Array`, for example, has an associated type, which is the type of its `Element`s...

Comment: Also, I just realised you edited your question... let me think about it for a moment...

Comment: Ok, two comments/questions: (1) if `Expression` is not the culprit, then the error is not in the `typealias` itself (which, I should have guessed from the nature of your error, sorry!)... The error is then in whatever you meant by 'using' the `typealias`... (2) Looking at your function's type, it does seam to be literally ported from objc, or is developed with that mindset... Again, if this is the case, it is a pity since Swift is opening whole new worlds... Parsing of mathematical expressions lends itself wonderfully to more functional ways of thinking and implementation...

Comment: @milos yeah, I don't really like the new language
I found a workaround by using a class with all the parameters (`[Expression]`, `[String: NSNumber]`, `inout AnyObject`) and use this instead.

Comment: but thanks for trying to help man

Comment: I understand. Well, as I have to go now, I'm going to make my final two suggestions: (1) Try reproduce your error with a minimal standalone code that you can then use to reformulate your question completely (by doing this you may well figure it out yourself!) (2) If you are sure you will never learn to enjoy programming in Swift (which I hope for your sake isn't true), then why programming in Swift at all? The problem you are having at the moment is just a prelude to a life of pain, unless you learn to appreciate the emerging pattens of working in Swift. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error (following an online tutorial), I removed all the code I entered before to get this error and the problem persist, it seems to me as the project was corrupted. I'm not an expert so please take this report with caution.

This is happened just after appeared an error HUD telling sourceKitService Crashed...

The probably offending code was this one:

---

```
         override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
     if var storedtoDoItems: AnyObject! = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("toDoItems") {

        toDoItems = []
         for var i = 0; i < storedtoDoItems.count; ++i {
             toDoItems.append(storedtoDoItems[i] as NSString)
          }
         println(storedtoDoItems)
    }

     taskTable.reloadData()
 }
```

---